# Simulate the results of rolling a die using Uniform[0, 1]

Tags: uniform-distribution

I saw this question in one of my textbooks:

> Let U be a random variable having a uniform(0,1) distribution. Describe how to simulate the outcome of the roll of a die using U.

I know that the outcome of rolling a die follows discrete uniform distribution with 6 outcomes, and each outcome has a probability of 1/6. I'm not quite sure how to approach this question. The straightforward solution I thought about was adding 6 `unif[0, 1]` distributions together to obtain the result of rolling a die. Would that be reasonable? If not, could someone correct me? Thanks!

Comment: Adding six uniform random variables will give you something where values close to $3$ are more likely than others, so not what you want.  Instead think about multiplication and rounding

Comment: Hint, To simulate flipping a coin, think about how the value of your uniform choice from $[0,1]$ compares to $1/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 6 different sides of the die are all equally likely with probability $\frac{1}{6}$. So if you are given another random variable, just partition its image set into six equally likely subsets.

In your case: If $X$ follows a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, just define a function $F : [0,1]\rightarrow \{1,...,6\}$ via
$$F(x) = 1, \text{ if } x \in\left[0,\frac{1}{6}\right],$$
$$\vdots$$
$$F(x) = 6, \text{if } x \in \left[\frac{5}{6},1\right],$$
and set $Y = F(X)$ as your new variable. This random variable will yield a number from $1$ to $6$ with probability of $\frac{1}{6}$ for each one, i.e. simulate the throw of a die.

Comment: Ah this makes sense. So it's just rounding up to an integer. Thanks!